# What do I need to log into Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

I had to reformat my OS since the last time I did any mining and so I don’t have any of the data originally on my HD. I do have my Geth account # and assuming I can remember my password is that sufficient to recover my account and transfer my ETH?

Alternatively was there a key of some kind of my old computer that is now lost which will inhibit me from being able to recover my ETH?

Answer (score 0):

first you have to start geth via

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal
```

next type `geth attach` in new console and and type `personal.unlockaccount(eth.coinbase)` next it ask you for your password and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Password is a way to access your private key which give real access to the network. If you have formatted your system unlikely your password could give access to the private key.